# pandas beautiful soup table export

Tags: python, pandas, selenium, beautifulsoup

I'm trying export table but my code causes error: 
ValueError: No tables found. Could anybody help me with it?

Code below:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.select import Select
import requests
import select
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.maximize_window()
browser.get('http://licytacje.komornik.pl/Notice/Search')
browser.find_element_by_xpath("//select[@name='Type']/option[text()='Nieruchomość']").click()
browser.find_element_by_class_name('button_next_active').click()
soup = BeautifulSoup(res.content,'lxml')
table = soup.find("table",{"class":"wMax"})
df = pd.read_html(str(table))
```

I've improved code. Now it looks like below:

```
import requests
import select
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.maximize_window()
browser.get('http://licytacje.komornik.pl/Notice/Search')
browser.find_element_by_xpath("//select[@name='Type']/option[text()='Nieruchomość']").click()
browser.find_element_by_class_name('button_next_active').click()
soup = BeautifulSoup(browser.page_source, "lxml")
table = soup.find("table",{"class":"wMax"})
df = pd.read_html(str(table))
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('test_licytacje.xlsx',engine='xlsxwriter')   
df.to_excel(writer,sheet_name='New1',startrow=0 , startcol=0)[0]
```

But currently last line of the code gives such error:
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'to_excel'

any feedback what's wrong, please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is your code is not logical:

```
df.to_excel(writer,sheet_name='New1',startrow=0 , startcol=0)[0]
```

The [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_html.html) for `read_html()` says it returns a list of DataFrames.  You are trying to invoke `to_excel()` on this list.  I guess you want this instead:

```
df[0].to_excel(writer,sheet_name='New1',startrow=0 , startcol=0)
```

Comment: Works, thansk a lot